# Use SMO DLL in Python using win32com

Tags: python, sql-server, smo, pywin32

I'm attempting to use the SQL Server SMO library from Python 2.7 using pyWin32. I can import `win32com`, but I've been stymied in any attempt to access the library. The code I am attempting is below.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies')
import win32com.client
server = win32com.client.Dispatch('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server')

def main():
    print server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When this code is run, I get `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)`.

It seems likely that I am simply getting the library's name wrong in the call to `Dispatch`, but I can't figure out any way to know what it should be.

---

It seems like this may actually be a path problem.

This works:

```
import win32api
win32api.LoadLibrary(r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll')
```

However, this does not:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies')
import win32api
win32api.LoadLibrary(r'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

win32com is for using COM libraries and it doesn't know anything about .NET assemblies. Currently, there is no way to use .NET directly from CPython, so your options are to [use IronPython](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Using_SMO_to_manage_a_MS_SQL_Database) or write a command line tool in C# or whatever and then call it from Python.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I didn't understand the distinction between COM libraries and .NET assemblies...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Pondlife's answer, which is correct for the question asked, it is possible to load .NET assemblies in CPython using the [Python for .NET](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/) module and the following code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
from Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo import Server
```

To make this work, I needed to add the assembly's path to `PYTHONPATH` manually. I couldn't get it to work using `sys.path.append`.

Comment: you can't run this on a linux box can you? is this for running smo in python on a windows box?

Comment: Correct, this is strictly a Windows solution.